# Php-Redis Issue

Tags: php, redis

I had installed Redis, Php and Php-Redis and now when i run this below program iam getting

```
<?php
   //Connecting to Redis server on localhost
   $redis = new Redis();
   $redis->connect('127.0.0.1', 6379);
   echo "Connection to server sucessfully";
   //check whether server is running or not
   echo "Server is running: "+ $redis->ping();
?>
```

The ideal output should be

**Connection to server sucessfully
Server is running: PONG**

but the ouput iam get

**Connection to server sucessfully**

where could be the issue?

Comment: does `echo $redis->echo('ping');` return 'ping'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should change this:

```
echo "Server is running: "+ $redis->ping();
```

to this:

```
echo "Server is running: " . $redis->ping();
```

Because the . operator is for Concatenation, and the + operator is for addition.

Comment: Thanks it worked. The tutorial here was wrong http://www.tutorialspoint.com/redis/redis_php.htm. Just blindly followed it.

Comment: I've mailed them their fault, lets hope they change it and make it logical!